# Measuring distance to national border

Tags: mapbox

I have a list of addresses and would like to know how far they are from the Mexican border. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would add a shape file of Mexico to the map in GeoJSON as a layer.

Then you can use turf.js to calculate the distance between your point (which you can geocode) into GeoJson and the GeoJson geometry.

This is a good tutorial which introduces turf.js and distance calculation (presumably you are opting to use Mapbox GL).

https://www.mapbox.com/help/analysis-with-turf/

This is a good start you can amend this to add your own Mexican Shape geometry.